# Flash AS3 draw TextField to BitmapData with rotation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to draw text to a bitmapData and allow it to be rotated but rotating the text makes it disappear :(

The code I am using resembles something like this :

```
var tf : TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "testing";

var mat : Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.identity();
mat.rotate(angle);
var img : BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 500, true, 0);

img.draw(tf, mat, null, null, null, true);
```

If I comment out mat.rotate(angle); the text appears fine.  It's not the angle value because I can do this :

```
var tf : TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "testing";

var mat : Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.identity();
mat.rotate(angle);
var img    : BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 500, true, 0);
var txtImg : BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 500, true, 0);

txtImg.draw(tf,      null, null, null, null, true);
img.   draw(txtImg , mat,  null, null, null, true);
```

and the text will appear rotated (which is a workaround to this problem but I need to create 2 BitmapData images and call draw twice which costs CPU and memory). I would much rather not have to do all this extra processing to get an effect that should, in theory, work with a single call to the draw method.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
tf.embedFonts = true;
```

If you don't use embedded fonts, Flash won't be able to do anything graphicaly advanced with your TextField.

---

**From @yesterday's comment** (for a better formatting):

For others that might have the same problem, I used the Embed tag to embed my font. Something along the line of :

```
[Embed(source='../libs/font.ttf', fontFamily='MyFont', embedAsCFF='false')] 
private const MyFont : Class;
```

and I call

```
Font.registerFont(MyFont);
```

somewhere in the code before using the font.

Comment: This is true for the old versions of Flash. As far as I can recall Flash 10.1 supports all transformations even with text fields with native fonts.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.  For others that might have the same problem, I used the Embed tag to embed my font.  Something along the line of : [Embed(source='../libs/font.ttf', fontFamily='MyFont', embedAsCFF='false')] private const MyFont : Class;  and I call Font.registerFont(MyFont); somewhere in the code before using the font.